# Como obter ID do Instagram da página da Empresa - API

Tags: api, facebook, instagram-api

Olá, tudo bem?

Estou realizando um projeto de BI para obtenção de análises do Instagram e preciso passar como parâmetro o ID da página para consumir o endpoint que busco para montar a análise, no artigo que li
"Discover Insights from Your Instagram Business Account with Facebook Graph API and Python" de Rizqi Maulana, ele aponta que gera o ID no momento da geração do Token, gerei o Token, mas não encontrei o  ID, saberia algum endpoint onde realiza a busca e obtenho esse parâmetro.

Endpoint buscado:
[https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/"instagram_account_id"/media](https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/%22instagram_account_id%22/media)

```
url = params['endpoint_base'] + params['instagram_account_id'] + '/media'
```

`endpointParams = dict() data = requests.get(url, endpointParams ) basic_insight = json.loads(data.content)`

Diante mão agradeço.

Att,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegue realizar a autenticação olhando essa dúvida pelo, o fórum da meta, o problema se deu por motivo de um bug encontrado nas permissões, que tinha que retirar todas as permissões que o aplicativo tinha e depois incluir novamente, com isso, ele se autenticou e mostrou o ID do instagram da conta.

Segue o link que verifiquei a solução que usei:
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/363766241696115/

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).